# Unable to locate package mail-stack-delivery

Tags: debian

I am trying to install dovecot in my Debian 6:

root@www:/# `apt-get install mail-stack-delivery`

And I get `E: Unable to locate package mail-stack-delivery`

Could some one please advise what repositories I need to add to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: Debian has no such package, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears an Ubuntu specific [meta package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mail/mail-stack-delivery) installing docecot's IMAP, POP3 and sieve services as well as postfix.

You can probably install each of those individually on Debian as well.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.  I can't find that package in Ubuntu's website.  It seems this package only existed until Ubuntu Focal, and was removed after that release: <https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mail-stack-delivery>